# Simulink bus, array lenth based on variable

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, simulink

I'm just starting with MatLab and as a PLC programmer I was wondering if it is possible to create a 'bus' based on an ARRAY of STRUCT were the size of the array is determined by a 'constant' variable.

So in CoDeSys I would make it like:

```
data : ARRAY [0..~length~] OF ~STRUCT~;
```

With ~STRUCT~:

```
Start : BOOL;
Stop  : BOOL;
```

And ~length~ = 3, this would result in:

```
data[0].Start
data[0].Stop
data[1].Start
data[1].Stop
data[2].Start
data[2].Stop
data[3].Start
data[3].Stop
```

How to make something similar within the 'BusEditor' in Matlab/Simulink? Please supply a step by step answer for dummies, as I'm a newbie with Matlab/Simulink. Thanks in advance.

Ludo

[image]
I think that the 'dimensions' is defining the array , but how to add a constant variable?